# How to enqueue script from shortcode with OOP in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

While developing a plugin, I've tried setting up a locally scoped state within my class so that I can call an observer method to call an enqueue_script function from within my shortcode. I'd like to be able to do this because I'm loading in Vue, and I don't want it to conflict with other areas of my site. After playing around for a while and reading docs online -- I can't find out where I'm going wrong.

My `set_user_form` function is currently loading in the framework, but I'd like to call `$this->observer()` from `get_user_form`. However, it's not loading the script from within the shortcode function.

Any idea where I can refactor this code to get the script to load properly?

```
<?php

namespace Usergen;

class UserInput {
  public $_state = array (
    'load_vue' => false
  );

  public function __construct() 
  {
    /**
     * Dependencies to sideload images into media gallery
     */
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
    // front end javascript dependency registered as callable script
    add_action( 'init', function() {
      wp_register_script( 'vue-js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue', array(), CRV_USER_GEN_VERSION, false );
    });

    // register user form as shortcode
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'set_user_form' ) );
    // register thank you page shortcode
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'set_user_submission' ) );
  }

  public function observer()
  {
    if ( $this->_state['load_vue'] ) {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'vue-js' );
    }
  }

  public function set_user_form() 
  {
    // load front end dependencies
    if ( !function_exists( 'user_generated_content' ) ) {
      add_shortcode( 'user_generated_content', array( $this, 'get_user_form' ) );
      $this->_state['load_vue'] = true;
      $this->observer();
    }
  }

  public function get_user_form() 
  {
    ?><div id="usergen" class="form">
      <div v-if="submitted">
        <p>Your submission was successful!</p>
      </div>
      <form v-else @submit="checkForm" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div v-if="errors.length">
          <strong>Please fix the following errors</strong>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <input v-model="name" id="first_name" type="text" name="crv_name" value="" placeholder="your name here" />
        <input v-model="email" id="email" type="email" name="crv_email" value="" placeholder="your email" />
        <label for="crv_story">Please include your social media account name so we can follow and tag you!</label>
        <textarea id="crv_story" name="crv_story" rows="2" placeholder="your story here"></textarea>
        <input id="files" type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" name="crv_featured_media[]" multiple="mulitple" />
        <br />
        <input id="instagram" type="checkbox" name="crv_social_media_allowed_1" value="instagram" />
        <label for="instagram">Instagram</label>
        <input id="facebook" type="checkbox" name="crv_social_media_allowed_2" value="facebook" />
        <label for="facebook">Facebook</label>
        <input id="twitter" type="checkbox" name="crv_social_media_allowed_3" value="twitter" />
        <label for="twitter">Twitter</label>
        <input id="consent" type="checkbox" name="crv_social_media_allowed_3" value="consent" />
        <label for="consent">I give consent to use these photos on their social media accounts.</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="crv_user_generated" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'crv_user_generated' ) ?>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
      </form>   
    </div>
    <script>
    var usergen = new Vue({
      el: "#usergen",
      data: {
        errors: [],
        name: null,
        email: null,
        submitted: false
      },
      methods: {
        checkForm: function(e) {
          if(this.name && this.email) {
            this.submitted = true;
            return true
          };
          this.errors = [];
          if(!this.name) this.errors.push("Name required");
          if(!this.email) this.errors.push("Email required");
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    })
    </script>
    <?php
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK most [often](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) `wp_enqueue_script` is called in function hooked on `wp_enqueue_scripts`

```
?php
  function wpb_adding_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('my_amazing_script', plugins_url('amazing_script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_script');
  }

  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );  
?>
```

to avoid conflict with other scripts you can use loading [dependency](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) by passing name of scripts in 3rd param  of `wp_register_script` function